# Winforms UI Dynamically Displaying Parts

Tags: c#, winforms

I came across a tutorial and some example code for an audio converter.  You select the format you want to convert to from a drop down, and when you do all sorts of options appear in a previously blank area, different options based on the format you choose.  It's called Audio Converter .NET and is from same author as Audio CD Ripper .NET.  I can't find the tutorial, but here is a screenshot.

[image]

See how on the right there is extra controls that are not on the left.  I was experimenting trying to add another category.  I added it to the dropdown, but am unsure how to make it so certain fields come up when it is selected.

I understand that they create those controls for those items, but I don't see how they call the correct one when the combo box selects something.  I see controls are created, but if I try to duplicate the controls into another entry in the combo box they don't show up for either the new or old one I was duplicating from.

What's the best way to go about achieving something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Try looking at the code-behind and see how the designer does it and then copy that code.

Comment: If an answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Comment: I was waiting there is a timer before I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create the controls needed for every option in the dropdown inside a panel, and simply turn it's `visibility` property from `false` to `true` whenever it's corresponding option is selected using the combobox's `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler. (And don't forget to turn the current visible panel's `visibility` to `false`)